# how to get row average for certain columns in r data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data that looks like this

```
t=c(3,2,9,8)
u=c(5,6,7,8)
v=c(3,2,1,9)
w=c(5,6,7,8)
x=c(1,2,3,4)
y=c(4,3,2,1)
z=data.frame(t,u,v,w,x,y)

output:
  t u v w x y
1 3 5 3 5 1 4
2 2 6 2 6 2 3
3 9 7 1 7 3 2
4 8 8 9 8 4 1
```

I would like to get the mean of each row for the first three columns, and then get the mean of each row for the last three columns. Ex. mean of row 1, columns t-v and mean of row 1, columns w-y, and so on.

Desired output:

```
  t u v avg w x y avg2
1 3 5 3 3.6 5 1 4 3
2 2 6 2 3.3 6 2 3 3.6
3 9 7 1 5.6 7 3 2 4
4 8 8 9 8.3 8 4 1 4.3
```

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more alternative using tidyverse is the `rowwise()` and `c_across`

```
z <- z %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(avg=mean(c_across(1:6)))
```

Comment: I probably should have mentioned this earlier, but while both these methods work on the mini data frame I created here, neither works on my data set because it's a tibble. It does not give any errors when I run it, but when I look at the table, the column was never added. Any suggestions?

Comment: I can add the full code to this post, but it's kind of long

Comment: @bandcar just assign to z: `z <- z %>%.....` and add `na.rm = TRUE`

Comment: Nope. Still didn't work. I'll just make a new post with this problem since I already marked it as answered.

Comment: @bandcar, assigning the this to a new or existing variable should solve that. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I was actually able to get it to work the first way you suggested. The reason I couldn't see the new columns is because I did not notice the arrows at the top that take you to the next page. lol

Comment: Great. I recommend reading some of the tidyverse blog pages as they do a great job teaching how to use these the "verbs". It may seem scary and unfamiliar at first but shortly you will get a great feel for them and it will feel natural.

Answer (score 2):

Use `rowMeans()`. Using column names:

```
z$avg <- rowMeans(z[c("t", "u", "v")])
z$avg2 <- rowMeans(z[c("w", "x", "y")])
```

Result:

```
  t u v w x y      avg     avg2
1 3 5 3 5 1 4 3.666667 3.333333
2 2 6 2 6 2 3 3.333333 3.666667
3 9 7 1 7 3 2 5.666667 4.000000
4 8 8 9 8 4 1 8.333333 4.333333
```

Alternative using column indices, with re-arranged output:

```
z$avg <- rowMeans(z[1:3])
z$avg2 <- rowMeans(z[4:6])
z <- z[c(1:3, 7, 4:6, 8)]
```

Result:

```
  t u v      avg w x y     avg2
1 3 5 3 3.666667 5 1 4 3.333333
2 2 6 2 3.333333 6 2 3 3.666667
3 9 7 1 5.666667 7 3 2 4.000000
4 8 8 9 8.333333 8 4 1 4.333333
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks so much

Comment: In case of NA in the data the code would fail. So implement `na.rm=TRUE` like `z$avg <- rowMeans(z[c("t", "u", "v")], na.rm = TRUE)`